# robocopy doesn't remove attributes from copied folders

Tags: robocopy, attributes

I try to use robocopy to copy all userdata from : "C:\Users"

Command:

```
robocopy /b /e /xjd /sl /a-:RSH /r:1 "C:\Users" "E:\backup"
```

In the User directories are hidden folders. The parameter /A-:RSH should remove those attributes:

> /a-:[RASHCNET] --- Removes the specified attributes from copied files.
>  R
> – Read only
>   A – Archive
>   S – System
>   H – Hidden
>  C – Compressed
>   N –
> Not content indexed
>  E – Encrypted
>   T – Temporary
>  O - Offline

For example: The folder "E:\backup\Default" (Source: C:\Users\Default) is still hidden and write protected on the destination drive. Can anyone explain why those attributes doesn't get removed ?

Regards, Int3g3r

PS: I tried this also with the /copy:DT parameter. If i understand this right the attributes should not getting copied when i use the /copy:DT parameter.
But this doesn't work either.

Comment: Files and Folders are not the same. Maybe this is the issue here.
The /a-: parameter is maybe only for FILES.
I add now the /dcopy:DT parameter and try it again.

Comment: The /dcopy:DT parameter doesn't work too. The directory "Default" is still hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the same issue is definitely fact.

My simple workaround -- put robocopy to a CMD script and add this line below the one calling robocopy.exe:

attrib -r -s -h "E:\backup\Default"